# How to grant privileges on trigger and synonyms in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, privileges

I have created a sample application to get schema of all objects and generate SQLfile, so I simply created two user, user 'SYSTEM' and 'SCOTT' , and user SYSTEM grant all privileges to access some of tables,views,function etc. to user SCOTT, 
for grant privileges to user SCOTT use following oracle query

```
GRANT ALL ON table_name to username
```

But the problem is this query is not working for trigger and synonyms.
so anyone please suggest me how can I grant privileges on triggers and synonyms to user SCOTT.

Answer (score 5):

> But the problem is this query is not working for trigger and synonyms. so anyone please suggest me how can I grant privileges on triggers and synonyms to user SCOTT.

- **TRIGGER** - You cannot t give grants for trigger. There is no such thing. Triggers fire automatically whenever the trigger event is done on the table on which the the trigger is created. You only need to grant privilege on the table.
- **SYNONYM** - You just create a synonym for the `schema.table` and grant privilege on the table such that other users doesn't have to fully qualify the table and just use the synonym instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
I am able to get ddl of alternative schema (schema other then login user) for all database's elements excepts TRIGGER and SYNONYMS. Because when I restore my data back to new database then I first need to generate same data structure and then make disable all trigger and constraints, then load data into database's tables and then make enable that trigger and constraints. So until unless I can't get ddl for TRIGGER and SYNONYMS, I can not create as well as restore my data to new database.
Can you give other solution to get DDL for TRIGGER AND SYNONYMS?

Comment: @Gracy Are you using `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` to retrieve the `DDL`?

Comment: yes, I am using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to retrieve DDL, 
BUT 
If the case when I get ddl schema of the login user then I get name of existing TRIGGER using the following query
 "select object_name from user_objects where object_type = 'TRIGGER'" ;
and then I use the trigger name in getDDL method and that return me the TRIGGER ddl sql.

In my case I want to get TRIGGER DDL of Other Schema (NOT OF THE SCHAMA OF LOGIN USER)
Here I cannt get name list of granted TRIGGERs, "This is the issue" [ and same for SYNONYMS ]
 
So if I get name of trigger then I can get ddl schema of the trigger too

Comment: `user_objects` only gives you the objetcs of current user. to get the list of objects of all the users, use `DBA_OBJECTS` if you have DBA privilege.

Comment: thank you Sir                                                                                               Is there any query to get triggers of only granted tables,means if I grant privileges on "DEPT" table to user scott then how can I get related indexes,triggers and Synonyms also.

Comment: @Gracy Create the required `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` for the required objects. It would hardly take few minutes using a good text editor. Just follow this article https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_metadata

Comment: @Gracy I would appreciate if you mark it as answered, would help others too! I hope you know how to do that, just click on the tick mark below the vote button, it will turn green :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about `GRANT SELECT ON dba_triggers to SCOTT;`

This way triggers will be visible to user Scott.